# Pydantic model for JSON Meta Schema

Tags: python, jsonschema, pydantic

I have a use case where user needs to define some JSON Schema for later usage. Right know I am using Pydantic parse user configs and check if they are ok.

Does any one know if there exist an library with Pydantic Model for JSON Meta Schema?
Even better would be if it could parse JSON Schema into Pydantic Model at runtime.

Comment: Pydantic docs point to code generation from JSON Schema: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to hack the utils out of [datamodel-code-generator](https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/), specifically their `JsonSchemaParser`. This generates an intermediate text representation of all pydantic models which you can then dynamically import. You might reasonably balk at this, but it does allow for self-referencing and multi-model setups at least:

```py
import importlib.util
import json
import re
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from types import ModuleType

from datamodel_code_generator.parser.jsonschema import JsonSchemaParser
from pydantic import BaseModel


NON_ALPHANUMERIC = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+")
UPPER_CAMEL_CASE = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+")
LOWER_CAMEL_CASE = re.compile(r"[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+")

class BadJsonSchema(Exception):
    pass


def _to_camel_case(name: str) -> str:
    if any(NON_ALPHANUMERIC.finditer(name)):
        return "".join(term.lower().title() for term in NON_ALPHANUMERIC.split(name))
    if UPPER_CAMEL_CASE.match(name):
        return name
    if LOWER_CAMEL_CASE.match(name):
        return name[0].upper() + name[1:]
    raise BadJsonSchema(f"Unknown case used for {name}")


def _load_module_from_file(file_path: Path) -> ModuleType:
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
        name=file_path.stem, location=str(file_path)
    )
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[file_path.stem] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module


@contextmanager
def _delete_file_on_completion(file_path: Path):
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        file_path.unlink(missing_ok=True)


def json_schema_to_pydantic_model(json_schema: dict, name_override: str) -> BaseModel:
    json_schema_as_str = json.dumps(json_schema)
    pydantic_models_as_str: str = JsonSchemaParser(json_schema_as_str).parse()

    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".py", delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_file_path = Path(temp_file.name).resolve()
        temp_file.write(pydantic_models_as_str.encode())

    with _delete_file_on_completion(file_path=temp_file_path):
        module = _load_module_from_file(file_path=temp_file_path)

    main_model_name = _to_camel_case(name=json_schema["title"])
    pydantic_model: BaseModel = module.__dict__[main_model_name]
    # Override the pydantic model/parser name for nicer ValidationError messaging and logging
    pydantic_model.__name__ = name_override
    pydantic_model.parse_obj.__func__.__name__ = name_override
    return pydantic_model
```

Main drawback as I see it- `datamodel-code-generator` has non-dev dependencies `isort` and `black`- not ideal to have in your deployments.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to generate Pydantic models from JSON schemas. [Here](https://koxudaxi.github.io/datamodel-code-generator/jsonschema/) is an implementation of a code generator - meaning you feed it a JSON schema and it outputs a Python file with the Model definition(s). It is not "at runtime" though. For this, an approach that utilizes the [`create_model`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation) function was also discussed in [this issue thread](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/643) a while back, but as far as I know there is no such feature in Pydantic yet.

If you know that your models will not be too complex, it might be fairly easy to implement a crude version of this yourself. Essentially the `properties` in a JSON schema are reflected fairly nicely by the `__fields__` attribute of a model. You could write a function that takes a parsed JSON schema (i.e. a dictionary) and generates the [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization) definitions to pass to `create_model`.

Comment: Then I will need to implement it myself... The goal is to replace existing legacy validation library (which uses JSON schemas as input) with Pydantic without rewriting old definitions

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly I believe you want to have a pydantic model that represents valid instances of JSON Schema.

I've had a look around for this before, and have always ended up rolling my own definition. Here is my lastest rendition, including a little tester script in the `main` function to show how it's used with another pydantic model's JSON Schema definition:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Optional, Any, Dict, Union, List
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import parse_obj_as


class Type(str, Enum):
    OBJECT = "object"
    ARRAY = "array"
    STRING = "string"
    NUMBER = "number"
    INTEGER = "integer"
    BOOLEAN = "boolean"
    NULL = "null"


class BaseJsonSchema(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str]
    description: Optional[str]
    default: Optional[Any]
    enum: Optional[List[Any]]

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class StringJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.STRING, const=True)
    minLength: Optional[int]
    maxLength: Optional[int]
    pattern: Optional[str]


class ObjectJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.OBJECT, const=True)
    properties: Optional[Dict[str, "AnyJsonSchema"]]
    required: Optional[List[str]]
    additionalProperties: Optional[Union[bool, "AnyJsonSchema"]]


class ArrayJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.ARRAY, const=True)
    items: Optional[Union["AnyJsonSchema", List["AnyJsonSchema"]]]
    minItems: Optional[int]
    maxItems: Optional[int]
    uniqueItems: Optional[bool]


class NumberJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.NUMBER, const=True)
    minimum: Optional[float]
    maximum: Optional[float]
    exclusiveMinimum: Optional[bool]
    exclusiveMaximum: Optional[bool]
    multipleOf: Optional[float]


class IntegerJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.INTEGER, const=True)
    minimum: Optional[int]
    maximum: Optional[int]
    exclusiveMinimum: Optional[bool]
    exclusiveMaximum: Optional[bool]
    multipleOf: Optional[int]


class BooleanJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.BOOLEAN, const=True)


class NullJsonSchema(BaseJsonSchema):
    type: Type = Field(Type.NULL, const=True)


AnyJsonSchema = Union[
    StringJsonSchema,
    ObjectJsonSchema,
    ArrayJsonSchema,
    NumberJsonSchema,
    IntegerJsonSchema,
    BooleanJsonSchema,
    NullJsonSchema,
]

ObjectJsonSchema.update_forward_refs()
ArrayJsonSchema.update_forward_refs()


def main():
    class Details(BaseModel):
        season: str
        temperature_celsius: float

    schema = parse_obj_as(AnyJsonSchema, Details.schema())
    print(schema)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    main()
```